# Change text of a listview, that is filled by an ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, text, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener

Is there any way to change the text in a listview, which is filled by an ArrayAdapter?

My array:

```
public String[] trainingstage = {"Hello", "Hello 2"};
```

The ArrayAdapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,

android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, trainingstage);

setListAdapter(adapter);

ListView listView = getListView();

listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

OnItem:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        switch (position) {
        //untrained
        case 0: 
         //here the text in the listview should change from "Hello" to "BYE"

        case 1:
        //here the text in the listview should change from "Hello 2" to "BYE 2" 
  }
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: You should use `getItemAtPosition`

Comment: Where should I use this?

Comment: I am working on an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want like this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
          long id) {

      TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

      switch (position) {
      //untrained
      case 0: 
       //here the text in the listview should change from "Hello" to "BYE"
          tv.setText("BYE");
          break;

      case 1:
      //here the text in the listview should change from "Hello 2" to "BYE 2" 
          tv.setText("BYE 2");
          break;
      }
  }
```

**What is android.R.id.text1**

- `ArrayAdapter`s constructor uses `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` xml layout as its second parameter and this layout has one child - `TextView` with ID `android.R.id.text1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think other solution is to modify your data and then use `notifyDataSetChanged`. For example:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0: 
            trainingstage[position] = "BYE 1"; // or trainingstage[0]
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;

        case 1:
            trainingstage[position] = "BYE 2"; // or trainingstage[1]
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        }
  }
```

Because you are already filtering the position, you could replace `trainingstage[position]` by `trainingstage[0]` or 1.